# Insert object in c++ list

Tags: c++

I have the follow program in c++. The objective is receive some logs (that came from filedata variable), parse the logs, and save them to object list.

The part to do the parse its working good. But i have a problem when i iterate the parsed vector and try to save some elements to the list. I can get the elements (for example: `elements.at(0)` i get the first column (timestamp) but when i save to my list, we save two times the log (in this case the `filedata` only have two logs), but we save two time the SAME log.

My cpp program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>

class UserLogRecord
{
public:
  std::string timestamp;
  std::string id; 
  std::string name; 
  std::string data;
};

std::vector<std::string> explode(std::string const & s, char delim)
{
  std::vector<std::string> result;
  std::istringstream iss(s); // sequence of characters
  for (std::string token; std::getline(iss, token, delim); )
  {
    result.push_back(std::move(token)); //transfer token to vector
  }
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  const char* filedata =
  "1496843100;2017-06-07 13:45:00;000002D8;2600;user1\n"
  "9999999999;2017-06-07 13:45:00;000002D9;2800;user2";

  std::vector<std::string> lines = explode(filedata,'\n');

  std::list<UserLogRecord* > userLogRecords;
  UserLogRecord* userLogRecord = new UserLogRecord;

  //vector
  for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
  {
    std::vector<std::string> elements = explode(lines[i], ';');
    userLogRecord->timestamp = elements.at(0);
    userLogRecord->id = elements.at(2);
    userLogRecord->name = elements.at(4);
    userLogRecord->data = elements.at(3);
    userLogRecords.push_back(userLogRecord);
  }

  //list of logs
  std::list<UserLogRecord* >::const_iterator itLog = userLogRecords.begin();
  while (itLog != userLogRecords.end())
  {
    std::cout << '\n' + (*itLog)->timestamp + '\n';
    std::cout << (*itLog)->id + '\n';
    std::cout << (*itLog)->name + '\n';
    std::cout << (*itLog)->data + '\n';
    ++itLog;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output (when iterate the list):

```
9999999999
000002D9
user2
2800

9999999999
000002D9
user2
2800
```

Expected output:

```
1496843100
000002D8
user1
2600

9999999999
000002D9
user2
2800
```

My program save two logs (this part is 'good', i only have two logs) but its save always the same (curiously it is the last log)

Comment: I already edit the post and put the correct code. Thanks

Comment: Did you debug this? Ask yourself this: *What are you pushing into your list?* It's a list of *pointers*. The *same* pointer is being pushed into the list repeatedly. There are no distinct records here. There is only *one*.

Comment: I am sure, with a good debugger you will find the problem. Hint: Look at your object `userLogRecord`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only using one `UserLogRecord` and simply modifying the data instead of adding a new element in the list.

`std::list::push_back` is adding a copy of a pointer to `UserLogRecord` which remains the same for all the iterations of the loop. The same pointer is pushed multiple times in the list and therefore all elements have the same data.

The following code would fix the issue. A new UserLogRecord is created for each iteration. You must however remember to free the allocated memory with `delete` when you don't need it anymore.

```
//vector
for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
{
    UserLogRecord* userLogRecord = new UserLogRecord;

    std::vector<std::string> elements = explode(lines[i], ';');
    userLogRecord->timestamp = elements.at(0);
    userLogRecord->id = elements.at(2);
    userLogRecord->name = elements.at(4);
    userLogRecord->data = elements.at(3);
    userLogRecords.push_back(userLogRecord);
}
```

Comment: Better still, use a `std::list<UserLogRecord>` and stop using naked pointers in the first place. There is *zero* evidence it does any good in this code *at all*.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Its works. I'm new with c++, so sometime i have this errors. 

Yes, i forgot the delete (and its very important). Witch place i need to put the delete? Because i cannot put inside the vector iteration but its only the place i can have access to userLogRecord because i declare inside for. Outside for i dont have access

Comment: Its only a test code this example. I'm bulding a real-time API and in this case i need to use pointers

Comment: @rrpik93 In this case you should make another loop to iterate on your list at the end and `delete` each element. But I think I might be better to not use pointers and use `std::list<UserLogRecord>` like @WhozCraig advised.

Comment: Ok thanks. Yes, with other loop i can free the memory.

Comment: Yes i know, but like i said its ony a simple c++ example code. I'm bulding a real-time API, so in this case i need to use pointers. Thanks

Comment: If you need to use pointers (and unless there is a polymorphic base or shared-containment, you all-but-certainly *don't* need to use pointers), then use [**smart pointers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) such as `std::unique_ptr<UserLogRecord>` or `std::shared_ptr<UserLogRecord>`, whichever is appropriate. Modern C++ programs should *not* use naked pointers. [**RAII**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) should be your goal. Seriously.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will study more about smart pointers ;)